# React warning MUI: A component is changing the default checked state of an uncontrolled SwitchBase after being initialized

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, controlled-component

I'm trying to render a mui Switch component with default checked value. But it isn't working and i'm getting the warning.

```
MUI: A component is changing the default checked state of an uncontrolled SwitchBase after being initialized. To suppress this warning opt to use a controlled SwitchBase. 3 useControlled.js:27
```

I have also tried setting `checked` property along with `onChange` but still it doesn't work! I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong here.

```
{details.schedule.days.map((d) => (
                <StyledTableRow>
                  <TableCell>
                    <Typography variant="subtitle1" fontWeight="bold">
                      {d.day}
                    </Typography>
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>
                    <FormControlLabel
                      control={
                        <Switch
                          onChange={(e, checked) => {
                            setDetails((p) => {
                              let prev = { ...p };
                              prev.schedule?.days?.find(
                                (el) =>
                                  el.day === d.day &&
                                  (d.open = e.target.checked)
                              );
                              return prev;
                            });
                          }}

                          defaultChecked={d.open}
                        />
                      }
                      labelPlacement="bottom"
                      label={d?.open ? `Open` : `Closed`}
                    />
                  </TableCell>
                </StyledTableRow>
              ))}
```

Comment: Try changing `defaultChecked` to `checked`

Comment: Hey. i tried setting `checked` property too. And it still defaults to false along with warning even when input it true.

Comment: Change `defaultChecked` to `checked` and then add an alternative like so `checked={d.open || false}`

Comment: The fallback value that @Sean suggested is what fixed this for me

Answer (score 19):

use "checked" instead of "defaultChecked" will address this waring

Comment: I got another error `A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component`. Is it possible to avoid both?

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting the same error when using the defaultChecked property on a controlled switch.

As mentioned in the comments you should use the checked property.

In the docs it says in regard to the defaultChecked property:

> Use when the component is not controlled

https://mui.com/api/switch/#props

Answer (score 3):

I got exactly the same error once I used a controlled checkbox and put `checked={value}` without `defaultValue` so prevent such an issue I had to add `defaultValue` you can set it `false` or `true` or whatever according to your logic

```js
<Controller
  control={control}
  name={`${item.id}`}
  defaultValue={!!evaluationDimensions?.[item.id]?.selected} 
  render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
    <FormControlLabel
      control={
        <Checkbox
          checked={value}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      }
    />
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

For my warning error to go away I had to specify if checked was true or false.

```js
                <FormControlLabel
                     control={
                        !isChecked ? (
                           <Checkbox checked={false} />
                        ) : (
                           <Checkbox checked={true} />
                        )
                     }
                     label={face}
                     onChange={() => handleChange(face)}
                  />
```

Comment: Although this could be shortened to use the `isChecked` property for the `checked` value, this was my issue also. I was getting the error when the MUI component was receiving `undefined` for it's value instead of an explicit boolean.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid both error, you can just use
`checked={!!d.open}` instead of `defaultChecked={d.open}`.
Because if your initial state is `null`, it will be treated as `undefined`. Put `!!` before the value, if it's null, it will be treated as `false`.